# Cannot go to "chrome://downloads/" in a newly opened tab with Selenium in Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test for Chrome browser. My problem is that somewhere in my test, I download something and it covers a web element. I need to close that download bar (I cannot scroll to the element). I searched a lot and narrowed down to this way to open the download page in a new tab:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('chrome://downloads/');");
```

It opens that new tab, but does not go to download page.

I also added this one:

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
driver.get("chrome://downloads/");
```

but it didn't work either.

I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

and

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+ "j").build().perform();
action.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(500);
```

but neither one even opened the tab.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you can't open local resources programmatically.
Chrome raises an error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://downloads/
```

Working solution is to run Chrome with following flags:

```
--disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\chrome_insecure"
```

But this trick doesn't work with Selenium Chrome Driver(I don't know actually why, a tried to remove all args that appears in `chrome://version`, but this doesn't helps).

So for me above solution is the only one that works:

C# example:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://downloads/")
```

There is another trick if you need to open downloaded file:

JavaScript example:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("downloads-manager")[0].shadowRoot.children["downloads-list"]._physicalItems[0].content.querySelectorAll("#file-link")[0].click()
```

Chrome uses Polymer and Shadow DOM so there is no easy way to query `#file-link` item.

Also you need to execute `.click()` method with JavaScript programatically because there is a custom event handler on it, which opens actual downloaded file instead of `href` attribute which point to url where you downloaded file from.

Answer (score 0):

I started with this post and ended up with the solution given below. This one works in Chrome 71. First I highlighted the control and then clicked it. 
The window object is actually the IWebDriver, the second method is called after the first one.

```
  internal void NavigateToDownloads()
        {
            window.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://downloads/");
        }
 internal void OpenFirstDownloadLinkJS()
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) window;
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByTagName('downloads-manager')[0].shadowRoot.children[4].children[0].children[1].shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('#content')[0].querySelector('#details > #title-area > #file-link').setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow;border: 2px solid red;');");
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByTagName('downloads-manager')[0].shadowRoot.children[4].children[0].children[1].shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('#content')[0].querySelector('#details > #title-area > #file-link').click();");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (I wrote it in Python, but it should work in Java too with very slight modifications):

```
#switching to new window
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

#opening downloads
driver.get('chrome://downloads/')

#closing downloads:
driver.close()
```